# SQL Contains - only match at start

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

For some reason I cannot find the answer on Google! But with the SQL contains function how can I tell it to start at the beginning of a string, I.e I am looking for the full-text equivalent to 
     LIKE 'some_term%'.

I know I can use like, but since I already have the full-text index set up, AND the table is expected to have thousands of rows, I would prefer to use Contains.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry that should be: LIKE 'some_term%'

Comment: But that is what I am looking for, the full-text equivalent to LIKE 'someword%'. I only want it to look for terms in the beginning of a string. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Ah - ok - well then check out Johnie Karr's answer - he shows how to do it and has a great link, too!

Comment: You can use `*` as a wildcard, but if you mean sentence starts with, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Do you want only those rows where your term is the start of the entire column? That's how it read to me, but everyone else seems to think that you meant the start of any individual word within the column. "Thousands" is a pretty small number for SQL Server. Using LIKE 'some_term%' should work fine. If you index the column you could even use it with millions of rows without much of a problem performance-wise.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Actually more like hundreds of thousands. But if it is not possible with FTS then I will give Tom's suggestion a go and just index the columns and use like. I know LIKE 'someterm%' should not used an index scan if an index is available. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You want something like this:

> Rather than specify multiple terms, you can use a 'prefix term' if the
>   terms begin with the same characters. To use a prefix term, specify
>   the beginning characters, then add an asterisk (*) wildcard to the end
>   of the term. Enclose the prefix term in double quotes. The following
>   statement returns the same results as the previous one.

```
-- Search for all terms that begin with 'storm'
SELECT StormID, StormHead, StormBody FROM StormyWeather
WHERE CONTAINS(StormHead, '"storm*"')
```

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/full-text-indexing-workbench/

Comment: Sorry this is half of what I want, I know about the prefix term, but it searches for all matches in the string. I only want the beginning (like the command LIKE 'someterm%').

Comment: For example, suppose I have rows with entries 'abcdef' and 'g abcdef'. Then LIKE 'a%' will return the first one, which is what I want. But CONTAINS(column, '"a*"') will return both. But I do not want the second since a is not the first character. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Umair: SQL Server fulltext search doesn't work that way. If you look for `a*` it will find any words that start with an `a` - it doesn't look at any words that might have come before that `a` .....

Answer (score 6):

You can use CONTAINS with a LIKE subquery for matching only a start:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM myTable WHERE CONTAINS('"Alice in wonderland"')
) AS S1 
WHERE S1.edition LIKE 'Alice in wonderland%'
```

This way, the slow LIKE query will be run against a smaller set

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of it to actually prepend a unique word to the beginning of every field in the table.

e.g. Update every row so that 'xfirstword ' appears at the start of the text (e.g. Field1). Then you can search for CONTAINS(Field1, 'NEAR ((xfirstword, "TERM*"),0)')

Pretty crappy solution, especially as we know that the full text index stores the actual position of each word in the text (see this link for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the similar issue. This is what I have implemented as a work around.

1. I have made another table and pulled only the rows like 'some_term%'.
2. Now, on this new table I have implemented the FullText search.

Please do inform me if you tried some other better approach